# How to send a request to caller to alert them a reject call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, agora.io

*index.js*

```
async acceptCall() {
          const tokenRes = await this.generateToken(this.agoraChannel);
          this.initializeAgora(tokenRes.data.appID);
    
          this.joinRoom(tokenRes.data.token, this.agoraChannel);
          this.incomingCall = false;
          this.callPlaced = true;
        },
    
        declineCall() {
          // You can send a request to the caller to
          // alert them of rejected call
          this.incomingCall = false;
        },
```

**Now my problem is when call has been declined, the caller could not get alert**

Answer (score 0):

Accept or reject calls using the Agora RTM SDK for a dynamic video call experience using the flow in: https://github.com/akshatvg/Agora-RTM-Call-Invitation

Docs: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_web?platform=Web